# IF-statement or something more efficient?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have 3 different variables that all 3 can have 2 different values. Every combination need to do something else. I can put it all into a IF statement, but I was wondering if there isn't a more elegant/proper/shorter solution. The 3 variables can have a value of 1 or 0 (like a binary truth table).

Comment: Nested if statements are the most efficient way of handling this decision tree.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

Comment: what you have tested so far?

Comment: Well, I didn't tested this yet. I know how to write the code with If statements. I was only wondering if there was a better solution. thank you all for the fast responses. I will stay with the if statements :o)

Comment: If you're wondering if your current solution is a good one, you can bring your fully functional, *real* code over to Code Review. Please take a minute to read about what's [on topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there before posting though.

Comment: This code review part is a very interesting idea. Thanks for the suggestions, I'm gone put it there.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not strictly more *efficient* than binary branching (unless you can predict the frequency of the arguments), one alternative is to use a peculiarity of VBA's syntax and put it in a `Select Case` structure:

```
Private Sub Example(one As Boolean, two As Boolean, three As Boolean)

    Select Case True
        Case one And Not two And Not three
            Debug.Print "Case 1"
        Case one And Not two And three
            Debug.Print "Case 2"
        Case one And two And Not three
            Debug.Print "Case 3"
        Case one And two And three
            Debug.Print "Case 4"
        Case two And Not three
            Debug.Print "Case 5"
        Case two And three
            Debug.Print "Case 6"
        Case three
            Debug.Print "Case 7"
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Case 8"
    End Select

End Sub
```

It's certainly easier to look at than the If alternative:

```
Private Sub Example2(one As Boolean, two As Boolean, three As Boolean)

    If one Then
        If two Then
            If three Then
                Debug.Print "Case 4"
            Else
                Debug.Print "Case 3"
            End If
        Else
            If three Then
                Debug.Print "Case 2"
            Else
                Debug.Print "Case 1"
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If two Then
            If three Then
                Debug.Print "Case 6"
            Else
                Debug.Print "Case 5"
            End If
        Else
            If three Then
                Debug.Print "Case 7"
            Else
                Debug.Print "Case 8"
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

When I benchmark against the worse case (separate runs, clearing the immediate window between each) the difference in performance is only on the order of 20ms over one million iterations. The vast majority of performance gains will come from determining the *order* you evaluate the variables - that is, which branches are more likely.